# Procedure stops when legacy, new error traps are next to each other

Tags: sql, error-handling, try-catch

We have a bunch of old stored procedures with legacy style error trapping.  I changed one the other day and included a newer TRY...CATCH block.  The stored procedure just stopped after the TRY/CATCH and returned as though there were an error in the legacy block.

If I put a

```
SELECT NULL
```

in between the two everything works fine.  Anyone know why this is happening?

```
--BEGIN NEW ERROR TRAP--
BEGIN TRY
Do stuff...
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
END CATCH
--END NEW ERROR TRAP---
----------------- OLD SCHOOL TRAP BEGIN -----------------
SELECT  @spERROR = @@ERROR ,
        @spROWCOUNT = @@ROWCOUNT
SET @spRETURN = @spRETURN + 1
IF ( @spROWCOUNT <= 0
     OR @spERROR <> 0
   ) 
    SET @spRETURN = 0 - @spRETURN
IF ( @spROWCOUNT <= 0
     OR @spERROR <> 0
   ) 
    RETURN @spRETURN
SELECT  @spROWCOUNT = -1 ,
        @spERROR = -1
------------------ OLD SCHOOL ERROR TRAP END ------------------
```

Comment: How do you know it stopped working? Your RETURN isn't always hit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your try catch block, the last statement is probably doing something that sets the row count to 0.  The "SELECT NULL" is setting the row count to 1, since it returns one row, so no error is detected.

You can fix this by changing the logic in the "old" code or by setting your row count variable in the try/catch code.  I would recommend that you remove the SELECT NULL, since it would guarantee success and you may not want that behavior.

Comment: What if I put the SELECT NULL at the end of the TRY section?

Comment: That will work to reset rowcount.  Do you need to keep the legacy code?  It would be cleaner to change everything to try/catch blocks.